# phpmyadmin configuration paths not working

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

os: ubuntu 18.04 lts
software: mariadb 10.5.10, nginx server 1.20.1, php version 7.2.34

phpmyadmin version: 5.1.1 (the latest one apparently)

Hello, I was trying to configure phpmyadmin, but I noticed that config changes are not sorting effect.
As far I know, the default path for config it is /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, and inside that config includes parent configs like /etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/*

So, on /etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/config.inc.php I setted blowfish_secret, but at the moment does not works, since I saw phpmyadmin and I was getting the blowfish_secret warning. "The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Ubuntu 18.04 currently packages phpMyAdmin version 4.6.6. The phpMyAdmin PPA for Ubuntu seems to currently be on version 5.0.4. Therefore, my conclusion is that you've installed phpMyAdmin manually rather than through the package manager.

The files under `/etc/phpmyadmin/` are maintained by the package manager; when you install phpMyAdmin manually, the configuration files are expected in the same directory as phpMyAdmin (which usually would be under the web root).

You should edit (or create) `config.inc.php` in the same folder you have uncompressed the phpMyAdmin files to, and you should place all the directives in there rather than splitting out things like the blowfish secret directive in to a separate file.